# How to create vImage_CGImageFormat for YCbCr image?

Tags: ios, accelerate-framework, vimage

I want to create a library that can convert any video frame captured using **AVCaptureDevice** to target pixel format. So, it must support `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`, `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange`, `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange` and optionally `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar`.

For performance I want to use Accelerate framework as it contains rich set of [conversion functions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/vimage_operations/conversion). As target pixel format may be different and is set by library user it'll be grate to use universal [vImageConvert_AnyToAny](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1399134-vimageconvert_anytoany) function:

> You use vImage's vImageConvert_AnyToAny(*:*:*:*:_:) function to
>   convert between Core Video or Core Graphics image data of arbitrary
>   color spaces and bit depths. The source and destination images are
>   described by one or more buffers. For example, a Y'CbCr image may be
>   composed of one buffer containing luminance information and one buffer
>   containing chrominance information.

To use this function I must create [vImageConverter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimageconverter) which define conversion between images. Constructors of this class require source and destination image format description in form of [vImage_CGImageFormat](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage_cgimageformat):

```
vImage_CGImageFormat in_format = ...;
vImage_CGImageFormat out_format = ...; 
vImageConverterRef converter = vImageConverter_CreateWithCGImageFormat(&in_format, &out_format, NULL, kvImagePrintDiagnosticsToConsole, &err);

if( err == kvImageNoError )
{
    vImage_Buffer *src_planes = ...;
    vImage_Buffer *dst_planes = ...;

    err = vImageConvert_AnyToAny(converter, src_planes, dst_planes, NULL,  kvImagePrintDiagnosticsToConsole);
}
```

The code is based on this Apple article: [Building a Basic Conversion Workflow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/vimage_operations/conversion/building_a_basic_conversion_workflow)

For `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` such vImage_CGImageFormat is simple and described in **vImage_Utilities.h**:

```
/*!
 * @struct vImage_CGImageFormat
 * @abstract A pixel format
 * @discussion A vImage_CGImageFormat describes the ordering of the color channels, how many there are,
 * the size and type of the data in the color channels and whether the data is premultiplied by alpha or not.
 * This format mirrors the image format descriptors used by CoreGraphics to create things like CGImageRef and
 * CGBitmapContextRef.
 *
 * This vImage_CGImageFormat:
 *
 *  <pre>@textblock
 *      vImage_CGImageFormat format = {
 *          .bitsPerComponent = 8,
 *          .bitsPerPixel = 32,
 *          .colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),                                    // don't forget to release this!
 *          .bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little,
 *          .version = 0,                                                                   // must be 0
 *          .decode = NULL,
 *          .renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault
 *      };
 *  @/textblock</pre>
 *
 * codes for a little endian ARGB8888 pixel, or what is called in the rest of vImage, BGRA8888. Note: for 16-
 * and 32-bits per component formats (int16_t, uint16_t, half-float, float) most vImage image filters assume
 * the data is in host-endian format. (The APIs in this header do not.) Host-endian is little endian for Intel
 * and ARM, big endian for PowerPC. If the data is not in host-endian format, then you may use
 * vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888 or vImageByteSwap_Planar16U to swap the image data byte ordering.
 *
 * Some examples:
 *  <pre>@textblock
 *      ARGB8888     ->  {8, 32, NULL, alpha first, 0, NULL, kCGRenderingIntentDefault}     alpha first = { kCGImageAlphaFirst, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst }
 *      RGBA8888     ->  {8, 32, NULL, alpha last,  0, NULL, kCGRenderingIntentDefault}     alpha last  = { kCGImageAlphaLast,  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,  kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast }
 *      BGRA8888     ->  {8, 32, NULL, alpha first | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little, 0, NULL, kCGRenderingIntentDefault}
 *      RGB888       ->  {8, 24, NULL, kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, 0, NULL, kCGRenderingIntentDefault}
 *      RGB565       ->  {5, 16, NULL, kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little, 0, NULL, kCGRenderingIntentDefault}
 *      ARGB1555     ->  {5, 16, NULL, alpha first | kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little, 0, NULL, kCGRenderingIntentDefault}
 *      RGBA16F      ->  {16, 64, NULL, alpha last | kCGBitmapFloatComponents | kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little, 0, NULL, kCGRenderingIntentDefault }
 *      CMYK8888     ->  {8, 32, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceCMYK(), kCGImageAlphaNone, 0, NULL, kCGRenderingIntentDefault  }
 *      ARGBFFFF premultiplied    ->  {32, 128, NULL, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapFloatComponents | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little, 0, NULL, kCGRenderingIntentDefault }
 *      ARGBFFFF not-premultiplied -> {32, 128, NULL, kCGImageAlphaFirst | kCGBitmapFloatComponents | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little, 0, NULL, kCGRenderingIntentDefault }
 *      ARGBFFFF, alpha = 1 ->        {32, 128, NULL, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapFloatComponents | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little, 0, NULL, kCGRenderingIntentDefault }
 *  @/textblock</pre>
 *
 *  Note that some of these formats, particularly RGB565 and 16F formats are supported by vImage but
 *  not necessarily CoreGraphics. They will be converted to a higher precision format as necessary by
 *  vImage in vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer().
 *
 *  By C rules, uninitialized struct parameters are set to zero. The last three parameters are usually zero, so can usually be omitted.
 *
 *  <pre>@textblock
 *      vImage_CGImageFormat srgb888 = (vImage_CGImageFormat){
 *          .bitsPerComponent = 8,
 *          .bitsPerPixel = 24,
 *          .colorSpace = NULL,
 *          .bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault };
 *  @/textblock</pre>
 *
 * To understand how these various parameters relate to one another, we can look at the process of converting from
 * one vImage_CGImageFormat format to another:
 *
 *  1) transform endianness of src format given by bitmapInfo to host endian  (except 8 bitPerComponent content)
 *  2) remove decode array transformation, and up convert to a higher range format as necessary to preserve precision / range
 *  3) convert src colorspace to reference XYZ colorspace (may cause upconvert to preserve range / precision)
 *  4) convert XYZ to destination colorspace + rendering intent
 *  5) convert to destination precision (given by bitsPerComponent)
 *  6) deal with any alpha changes (given by bitmapInfo) or flattening that needs to occur
 *  7) Apply any channel reordering requested, if it didn't happen at an earlier step. (As indicated by src and dest bitmapInfo)
 *  8) Apply destination decode array
 *  9) Apply endianness transform given by dest bitmapInfo
 *
 * Clearly, for most common transformations not all steps need to occur and multiple steps can be collapsed into a compound operation.
 *
 *  @field  bitsPerComponent    The number of bits needed to represent one channel of data in one pixel. For ARGB8888, this would be 8. Expected values: {1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 16, 32}
 *  @field  bitsPerPixel        The number of bits needed to represent one pixel. For ARGB8888, this would be 32.
 *                              It is possible that bitsPerPixel > bitsPerComponent * number of components, but in practice this is rare.
 *                              The number of color components is given by the colorspace and the number of alpha components (0 or 1) is given by
 *                              by the bitmapInfo.
 *  @field  colorSpace          A description of how the pixel data in the image is positioned relative to a reference XYZ color space.
 *                                  See CoreGraphics/CGColorSpace.h.  Pass NULL as a shorthand for sRGB. The vImage_CGImageFormat is not
 *                                  capable of managing the memory held by the colorSpace. If you created the colorspace, you must
 *                                  be sure to release it before all references to it disappear from scope.
 *  @field  bitmapInfo          The CGBitmapInfo describing the color channels. See CoreGraphics/CGImage.h.
 *                                  ARGB8888 is kCGImageAlphaFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault
 *                                  BGRA8888 is kCGImageAlphaFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little
 *  @field  version             The struct is versioned for future expansion.  Pass 0 here.
 *  @field  decode              Prior to transformations caused by the colorspace, color channels are subject to a linear transformation.
 *                              This allows for a different range than the typical [0,1.0]. NULL indicates default behavior of [0,1.0]
 *                              range, and is what you should use if you don't understand this parameter. See description of CGImageCreate()
 *                              for a discussion of decode arrays. See also Decode Arrays section of Chapter 4.8 of the PDF specification.
 *                              The vImage_CGImageFormat is not capable of managing the memory held by the decode array. If you created a
 *                              decode array on the heap, you must be sure to release it before all references to it disappear from scope.
 *
 *  @field renderingIntent      See CGColorSpace.h. kCGRenderingIntentDefault is typical here. By convention, rendering intent changes that
 *                              are not accompanied by a colorspace change are ignored.
 */
```

I don't understand how to create vImage_CGImageFormat for YCbCr pixel format.

First I think it isn't supported at all but there are special functions for this format: [Understanding YpCbCr Image Formats](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/vimage_operations/conversion/understanding_ypcbcr_image_formats) and vImageConverter has special functions for multi plane images such as [vImageConverter_GetNumberOfSourceBuffers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1399124-vimageconverter_getnumberofsourc) and [vImageConverter_GetSourceBufferOrder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1399110-vimageconverter_getsourcebuffero). In the last function there are many [vImage Buffer Type Codes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/vimage_operations/conversion/1399056-vimage_buffer_type_codes) and even `kvImageBufferTypeCode_CVPixelBuffer_YCbCr`.

So, it looks like it is possible to create vImageConverter for YCbCr and I need help to find out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vImageConverter_CreateWithCGImageFormat` creates a converter for converting between two Core Graphics formats.

In this case, shouldn't you be using `vImageConverter_CreateForCVToCGImageFormat` to convert from a `CVPixelBuffer` (with a `vImageCVImageFormat` that you can generate using `vImageCVImageFormat_CreateWithCVPixelBuffer`) to a `CGImage`? The `vImage_CGImageFormat` is your destination format – so the properties of that are up to you to define.

Comment: I've missed vImageConverter_CreateForCVToCGImageFormat, thank you. With it and with vImageConverter_CreateForCGToCVImageFormat I can convert from CV to CG images and vice versa. But I doesn't see functions for conversion from CV to CV images. For example from kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange to kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar. Is there something builtin for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is function [vImageCreateRGBColorSpaceWithPrimariesAndTransferFunction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1498273-vimagecreatergbcolorspacewithpri) to create appropriate color space for YCbCr pixel format but only for converting from or to RGB format:

```
const vImageTransferFunction f709 =
{
    .c0 = 1.099,
    .c1 = 1.0,
    .c2 = 0.0,
    .c3 = -0.099,
    .gamma = 0.45,
    .cutoff = 0.018,
    .c4 = 4.5,
    .c5 = 0
};

const vImageRGBPrimaries p709 =
{
    .red_x = .64,               // 1.3 red
    .green_x = .30,             // 1.3 green
    .blue_x = .15,              // 1.3 blue
    .white_x = 0.3127,          // 1.4 white

    .red_y = .33,               // 1.3 red
    .green_y = .60,             // 1.3 green
    .blue_y = .06,              // 1.3 blue
    .white_y = 0.3290           // 1.4 white
};

vImage_Error err = kvImageNoError;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = vImageCreateRGBColorSpaceWithPrimariesAndTransferFunction( &p709, &f709, kvImageNoFlags, &err );

vImage_CGImageFormat format = {
    .bitsPerComponent = 8,
    .bitsPerPixel = 32,
    .bitmapInfo = (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
    .colorSpace = colorSpace
};
```